# Python p run code at the top or start of a new minute

Tags: python, python-2.7

In python, I have code that needs to be triggered and the top of every minute.  I have a while loop.  What is the best why to watch the time and when a new minute start then execute?

Thanks

```
 while True:
   if TOP_OF_MIN:
        run_code()
```

Comment: Better use a scheduler such as `cron` for Unix'es or `at` for Windows'es.

Comment: not every 60 seconds.  At the top of the minute and no I dont need a cron.  Thanks

Comment: Why the close votes? The question is clear, specific and not a duplicate of the linked question (The scheduler might be one approach to doing things on the whole minute, but schedulers can delay for up to a minute... so I wouldn't recommend doing it this way.)

Answer (score 2):

A minute is a looooong time in a program. Find out how many seconds are left in this minute, sleep for this long, then sleep 60 seconds per cycle-- or just keep checking the seconds, which guards against gradual drift.

```
while True:
    now = time.localtime().tm_sec
    time.sleep(60 - now)  # `now` is between 0 and 59, so we always sleep
    print("tick")
```

If you need better than second accuracy, use one of the functions that return the number of seconds as a fraction (e.g., `time.time()`)